# Delete .xcdatamodel file from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I made a lightweight migration that I decided I don't want anymore.  Is there any way to just delete the file?  I've already changed the current model version to the one before it, and the app runs.  However, when I right-click on the .xcdatamodel file in the Xcode file viewer, "Delete" is greyed-out.  I also tried to remove the file from Finder, but it keeps the file in Xcode, redded-out.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm curious if anyone answers this. The only way I could find to do it was to manually edit the project file and remove it.

Comment: Use git for all your projects. It is very easy to see exactly what changed and revert then.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes - having done this a lot, to my knowledge the only way is to open up YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj in your favourite raw text editor (vim ftw!), and search for and remove both instances of the offending model file. Ie:

```
D6A5760112F22213004DEDCE /* MyModel.xcdatamodeld */ = {
  isa = XCVersionGroup;
  children = (
    D6EDB44614ED9D7E00C02938 /* MyModel-V12.xcdatamodel */,
    D6931E6214D78135007F0E03 /* MyModel-V11.xcdatamodel */,
    D61403DD14B7857100323E6D /* MyModel-V10.xcdatamodel */,
    D675476B149BD1F3007C160C /* MyModel-V9.xcdatamodel */,
    D6199DD5143DE428002869C1 /* MyModel-V8.xcdatamodel */,
  );
  currentVersion = D6EDB44614ED9D7E00C02938 /* MyModel-V12.xcdatamodel */;
  name = MyModel.xcdatamodeld;
  path = aPath/MyModel.xcdatamodeld;
  sourceTree = "<group>";
  versionGroupType = wrapper.xcdatamodel;
};
```

So in this case, I go hunting for the two instances of `D6199DD5143DE428002869C1` and delete them both from the project file, and bang: Bob's my uncle. Also - you can reorder that chunk of children above in case you want the current one higher.

After I do that, I typically execute a manual source repo delete command on just the model-V8 dir too.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up just not using my unwanted .xcdatamodel file until I needed to (with a new migration), but this looks like the best *real* solution out there.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this problem. I also find out there are more files ready for a probable deletion, for example inside the xcdatamodel itself

Comment: Incidentally, this is also the technique I use to reorder the rows fwiw.

Comment: No problem! I'm amazed this continues to get upvotes... from 2012 :)

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done removing the `.xcdatamodeld` from the project (just removing, not deleting). Then, in Finder (or Terminal) deleting the *offending* `.xcdatamodel` file. And finally, reimporting the `.xcdatamodeld` in the project.

Comment: This is perhaps a simpler method?!?