# cannot edit .xcworkspace/contents file

Tags: xcode, ide, editing

After deleting unwanted .xcdatamodeld files in "YourProject".xcodeproj file, I encountered 3 new warnings linked to the "YourProject".xcWorkspace file.  The warnings are:

- contents is missing from working copy
- .xccurrentversion is missing from working copy
- contents is missing from working copy

After editing .xcodeproj/project.pbxproj, I tried to unpackage contents in .xcworkspace file.  At this point, Xcode and my text editor does not allow me to edit .xcworkspace/contents.  Any ideas how to edit this file, and remove the above three warnings?

I tried to follow the rare solution found on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649230/delete-xcdatamodel-file-from-xcode/43403047#43403047) to remove xcdatamodels, but clearly the solution does not address the warnings that occur when a .xcworkspace file is still looking for the old project files successfully removed from .xcodeproj.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to edit the above warnings by opening/editing .xcworkspace/..., I followed the advice in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338428/xcode-issue-file-xxx-png-is-missing-from-working-copy-at-project-building) about missing ****.png files and the similar warnings.  Warnings disappeared as soon as I made the latest commit to Github.